# Div isn't vivisble in Chrome and Opera

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, opera

I have this html code:

```
<div id="social">
                <div class="barra_gris"></div>
                <div class="caixa_social"><a class="twitter" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt="twitter" /></a>
                <a class="facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/grup-abs/329596937580" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook.png"  /></a>                      
                </div>
                <div class="idiomes"><a href="index.php?s=<? echo $s; ?>&p=<? echo $p; ?>&i=0">català</a> | <a href="index.php?s=<? echo $s; ?>&p=<? echo $p; ?>&i=1">castellano</a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="logo"><a href="index.php?s=1&i=<? echo $i; ?>"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a></div>
        </div>
```

And barra_gris has this css:

```
.barra_gris{
    position:relative;
    width:905px;
    height:15px;
    background-color:#6b6b6b;
    display: block;
}
```

The problem is that Chrome and Opera doesn't show the `barra gris` class with this background?

The url of site is: http://abs.marcmorales.es/

What could the problem be?

Comment: It does show at my end. Chrome

Comment: In my chrome version 16 in Mac doesn't show!

Comment: Morales Valllsomething I've tested it and it does work in: FF 8, Chrome 16 and 18 and IE 9. Are your sure it isn't some adblocker which is removing the bar?

Comment: @MarcMoralesValldepérez , Are you looking for bar upside down. In that case you need to set `height:100%`

Answer (score 0):

Add `&nbsp;` between the div and it will work like following

```
<div class="barra_gris">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Please don't add a nonbreaking-space if you don't need it.

Comment: in dat case he can use `min-width:905px;` in his CSS. Hope dat works

Comment: I put it:.barra_gris{
 position:relative;
 width:905px;
 min-width:905px;
 min-height:15px;
 background-color:#6b6b6b;
 display: block;
}

Answer (score 0):

In Google, Opera and IE I can see the grey bar on top with twitter and facebook logos plus the language options for Catala and Castellano. Plus the grey bar on top of the page... http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/267/barragris.png/

Comment: yes, marc, it's a 905px WIDTH, so it goes from one side of the screen to the other. Only 15px thick, you can see in the picture what I am seeing. Unless you want 905px from the top down (which would cover pretty much the whole screen height) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since this Div does not contain any data so by default its height becomes 0. So either put some height to this div or use